# How to parameterize query with like operator in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to parameterize Sql Query with like operator but it's not working. Both Search Criteria and Search text will be through Variable. Here what I am doing

```
declare @Query nvarchar(500), @SearchBy nvarchar(50) = 'PtName', @SearchText nvarchar(50) = 'Sh'
set @Query = 'select Id, PtName, Y, M, D, Sex, PtCode, ReceiptDate, ReferBy, RefDrCd, PtTitle, NetAmount, IncentiveAmount, PaidAmount, DueAmount, Investigation, LabCode, LabName, DiscAmount, PNo  FROM DiagMain where '+@SearchBy+' like '+@SearchText+' %'
    exec(@Query)
```

Please Help.

Comment: It would help us if you gave the error message it's giving. It would help you if you first *print* any SQL you've assembled by string concatenation and see if it looks reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(500), @SearchBy NVARCHAR(50) = 'PtName', @SearchText NVARCHAR(50) = 'Sh'
SET @Query = 'select Id, PtName, Y, M, D, Sex, PtCode, ReceiptDate, ReferBy, RefDrCd, PtTitle, NetAmount, IncentiveAmount, PaidAmount, DueAmount, Investigation, LabCode, LabName, DiscAmount, PNo  
FROM DiagMain where '+@SearchBy+' like '''+@SearchText+'%'''

PRINT @Query
EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: @shaiwal Tripathi IN Dynamic SQL query for String Variable Closing Should be '''variable Name ''' Like this and Print The String_SQL to Check whether The query you Execute Is Proper or Not. it will you out in Solving Issue

Comment: if it's work's for you can vote And Accept The Answer

Comment: I'd immediately search for `';DROP TABLE DiagMain;--`. Good luck.