# Set sql query with LIKE operator in mssql

Tags: sql-server

I am getting error on % operator while executing. Can you please help me to write proper way.

```
SET @sql = N'DELETE TOP(1000) FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ItemId
        in (Select ItemId from dbo.History_Item 
            WHERE (
                [FullyQualifiedName] LIKE ''' + @machine_DS + '.%'''
                OR 
                [FullyQualifiedName] Like '''+ @machine_Kpi + '.%'''
                )
            )
        AND datetime between'''+ @startDate +''' And '''+ @endDate +'''
```

I followed this link
[How to parameterize query with like operator in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45708982/how-to-parameterize-query-with-like-operator-in-sql-server)

But unable set it perfectly. I know it is duplicate query but I am facing trouble to set it.

Comment: Your ' are set wrong

Comment: Can you explain briefly where I am wrong?

Comment: i think you are using a dot(.) before '%'.

Comment: dot is not an issue, it should be just a string to find adress. After dot I am looking for string in table.

Comment: In addition to too many single quotes, `between'''+ @startDate +'''` is missing a space between `between` and `'''` - also, why are you appending dates and strings to a query instead of passing properly typed parameters? You should read up on SQL injection - a much more important reason to avoid this clumsy string concatenation than dealing with quotes.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand How to avoid it , because it will be internal query so I used it like that. Can you please send me suggestions.

Comment: I can't explain to you how to fix this in a comment. I suggest reading up on "SQL injection" (e.g. [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/) / [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)) and "parameterized SQL Server queries" (e.g. [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2981/using-parameters-for-sql-server-queries-and-stored-procedures/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

> NB do you really want to use .% in your like operator?

**SQL Code**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @tablename nvarchar(max) = 'test'
declare @machine_ds nvarchar(max) ='testmachine'
declare @startdate nvarchar(max) = '2018-06-25'
declare @enddate nvarchar(max) = '2018-06-26'
declare @machine_Kpi nvarchar(max) ='testmachinekpi'

SET @sql = 'DELETE TOP(1000) FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ItemId

 in (Select ItemId from dbo.History_Item 
            WHERE (
                [FullyQualifiedName] LIKE ''' + @machine_DS + '.%''
                OR 
                [FullyQualifiedName] Like '''+ @machine_Kpi + '.%''
                )
            )
        AND datetime between'''+ @startDate +''' And '''+ @endDate +''''

       print @sql
```

**SQL Code without injection**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @tablename nvarchar(max) = 'test'
declare @machine_ds nvarchar(max) ='testmachine'
declare @startdate date = '2018-06-25'
declare @enddate date = '2018-06-26'
declare @machine_Kpi nvarchar(max) ='testmachinekpi'

SET @sql = 'DELETE TOP(1000) FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ItemId

 in (Select ItemId from dbo.History_Item 
            WHERE (
                [FullyQualifiedName] LIKE ''' + @machine_DS + '.%''
                OR 
                [FullyQualifiedName] Like '''+ @machine_Kpi + '.%''
                )
            )
        AND datetime between @StartDate And @EndDate'

        exec sp_executesql @SQL,N'@StartDate date, @EndDate date',@StartDate = @startdate,@EndDate = @enddate
```

**SQL Output**

```
DELETE TOP(1000) FROM test WHERE ItemId

 in (Select ItemId from dbo.History_Item 
            WHERE (
                [FullyQualifiedName] LIKE 'testmachine.%'
                OR 
                [FullyQualifiedName] Like 'testmachinekpi.%'
                )
            )
        AND datetime between'2018-06-25' And '2018-06-26'
```

Comment: You could further avoid injection by also constructing parameters for the two string parameters.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Your right. I was just giving an example with the dates, because that was the most obvious one. But your 100 pct correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just edited your sql script

```
SET @sql = N'DELETE TOP(1000) FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ItemId
        in (Select ItemId from dbo.History_Item 
            WHERE (
                [FullyQualifiedName] LIKE ''' + @machine_DS + '.%''
                OR 
                [FullyQualifiedName] Like '''+ @machine_Kpi + '.%''
                )
            )
        AND datetime between'''+ @startDate +''' And '''+ @endDate +''''
```